# kill a task with name containing whitespace using python os.system

Tags: python, whitespace, taskkill

From a python script, I am trying to terminate a task.
The task name contains whitespace.

Like "My Program.exe" for instance.

I use the following line but it complains about invalid argument because the name contains a whitespace.

```
os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM My Program.exe")
```

I can't find how to escape the whitespace.

I tried

```
os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM "My Program.exe"") 
os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM \"My Program.exe\"")
os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM 'My Program.exe'")
os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM \'My Program.exe\'")
```

But still does not work.

Comment: Use single quote os.system('...')

Comment: `os.system('TASKKILL /F /IM "My Program.exe"')`

Comment: Thanks @ŁukaszRogalski it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM \"My Program.exe\"")
```

Check if your application is really named 'My Program.exe' on task manager. Also, check if you have privileges to be killing that process.

Comment: thanks @Renato, this works too. I don't know why my first attempt failed with this combination. I must have been tricked by my editor. It automatically inserts 2 double quotes when I strike the " key.